# How can I figure out why BigQuery is rejecting my parquet file?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery, parquet, parquetjs

When trying to upload a parquet file into BigQuery, I get this error:

```
Error while reading data, error message: Read less values than expected from: prod-scotty-45ecd3eb-e041-450c-bac8-3360a39b6c36; Actual: 0, Expected: 10
```

I don't know why I get the error.

I tried inspecting the file with parquet-tools and it prints the file contents without issues.

The parquet file is written using the parquetjs JavaScript library.

Update: I also filed this in the BigQuery issue tracker here: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/145797606

Comment: sorry for being picky but is the question about "how you can figure out?" or more " why BQ rejecting your file?" i am really interested to know as answer(s) would be quite different I think

Comment: can you share the sample parquet file on the bigquery issue tracker?

Comment: if anything, share the job id in the issue tracker

Comment: I wanted to know in general how to debug it.  However, I was able to debug this particular file without getting any general methodology besides trial and error.

Answer (score 2):

It turns out BigQuery doesn't support the latest version of the parquet format.  I changed the output not to use the version 2 format and BigQuery accepted it.

Comment: Did you file a request to get this format supported on the issue tracker? If you haven't, I will. Any sample file?

Comment: Parquet V2 is not considered production. If ParquetJS is writing this by default you should ask them to change it

Comment: @FelipeHoffa  I filed https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/145797606 for this issue, and left a comment that parquet v2 was the problem

Comment: @WesMcKinney Yeah, that might be a good idea.  Ideally BigQuery would have rejected the file with a better error in this case anyway.

Answer (score 1):

From the error message it seems like a rogue line break might be causing this.

We use DataPrep to clean up our data, it works quite well. If I am wrong it's also google recommended method of cleaning up / sanitising data for big query.

https://cloud.google.com/dataprep/docs/html/BigQuery-Data-Type-Conversions_102563896

Comment: I don't have any affiliation with Dataprep or Google Cloud. However I have used the product and am a big fan. I could have worded it a little better so I apologise if it came across like that. Would appreciate a more constructive response / suggestion, am only trying to help here :)